# What order of precedence does ∑ have?

Tags: math, operator-precedence

Trying to implement a neural network algorithm here, but I'm a bit lost on the math side of things:

Note that p and i should be subscript (not sure how to do it in stackoverflow).

(ΣpΣi(tpi - opi)^2) / (n * k)

Basically my question is concerning the inner ∑ : Do I sum (for all i (tpi - opi)^2)? Or do I square (the sum for all i (tpi - opi))?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sum of squares. So Σi(tpi - opi)^2 means (tp1 - op1)^2 + ... + (tpn - opn)^2. If you wanted square of sum it would be written most likely as (Σi(tpi - opi))^2. Also since its neural nets you probably mean the sum of squares.